# React does not find the url in React

Tags: javascript

Hi am performing LoginValidation on form submit. I call method validatelogin onsubmit. Method is as given below,

```
ValidateLogin(e)
{
    if(this.state.formValid)
    {
        let userid = this.state.userId;
        let password = this.state.password;
         let url = "http://localhost:3727/api/Login/ValidateUser";
            fetch(url, {
            method: "POST",
            mode: 'no-cors',
            body : "userid=" + userid +"&password=" +  password
            }).then((response) => console.Log(respose));
    }
};
```

With code get execute it shows url not found return 404  but same url is working from postman. This url accept only post request.
Not getting any clue whats going on. Do we have to register some endpoint in React to work for api calls?

Comment: Hello Pavan, your question actually has nothing to do with React. React is just a way of presenting a user interface in the browser. You should change the tags of your question to JavaScript, for example. The reason why your request does not work is most likely related to the restriction the browser imposes on cross-origin resource sharing, so you may want to look for related questions that explain how to make this work, there are many, with good, helpful answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this**. it's working on my case. please make sure client and service are in the same domain and same port(cors is not an issue).

```
ValidateLogin(e)
{
    if(this.state.formValid)
    {
        let userid = this.state.userId;
        let password = this.state.password;
         let url = "http://localhost:3727/api/Login/ValidateUser";
            fetch(url, {
            method: "POST",
            headers: new Headers({
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', // <-- Specifying the Content-Type
            }),
            mode: 'no-cors',
            body : "userid=" + userid +"&password=" +  password
            }).then((response) => console.Log(respose));
    }
};
```

Comment: this is not showing an error now but not working .. it's not hitting the api method

Comment: Which technologies are used to develop your service?

Comment: dotnet webapi2.0

Comment: Please check this.
<webServices>
    <protocols>
        <add name="HttpGet"/>
        <add name="HttpPost"/>
    </protocols>
</webServices>

Comment: [ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true)]
public string ValidateUser()
{
    return "Hello World";
}

Comment: please make sure client and server port is same.

Comment: This was due to API and UI were not in same domain